# find first 5 maximum values in each line using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I am trying to read a text file like the following

```
word 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
hello 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.8 0.6 0.1 0.9
```

I would like to print the word, "hello", and the maximun 5 values along with the number of the column where they are, like this using awk:

```
hello 10 0.9 7 0.8 6 0.7 8 0.6 3 0.5
```

I have thought something like this `awk '{ for (i=1; i <= 10; i++) a[$i]=$i};END{c=asort(a)?? for(i in a)print i,a[i]??}'`, but I would like to print in each line read.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk 4.* for sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc" }
NR>1 {
    split($0,a)
    printf "%s", a[1]
    delete a[1]
    for (i in a) {
        printf " %d %s", i, a[i]
        if (++c == 5) {
            c=0
            break
        }
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
hello 10 0.9 7 0.8 6 0.7 8 0.6 4 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You stated *[you] would like to print in each line read* so no limits to records read:

```
$ awk '{delete a; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {a[$i]=$i; b[$i]=i}; n=asort(a); printf "%s: ",$1; for(i=n; i>n-(n>=5?5:n); i--) printf "%s %s ", b[a[i]], a[i]; printf "\n"}' test.in
word: 11 10 10 9 9 8 8 7 7 6 
hello: 10 0.9 7 0.8 6 0.7 8 0.6 4 0.5
```

Walk-thru version:

```
{
  delete a                        # delete the array before each record
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {          # from the second field to the last
    a[$i]=$i                      # set field to array index and value
    b[$i]=i                       # remember the field number 
  }
  n=asort(a)                      # sort the a array
  printf "%s: ",$1                # print the record identifier ie. the first field
  for(i=n; i>n-(n>=5?5:n); i--)   # for the 5 (or value count) biggest values
    printf "%s %s", b[a[i]], a[i] # print them out
  printf "\n"                     # enter after each record
}
```

If a value repeats, it's only printed once.

Answer (score 0):

here is an `awk` assisted Unix tool set solution.

```
$ awk -v RS=" " 'NR==1; NR>1{print NR, $0 | "sort -k2nr"} ' file | head -6 | xargs
hello 10 0.9 7 0.8 6 0.7 8 0.6 4 0.5
```

I think your expected output has some typos.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and there is any way to instead of `head -6` that only print the first 6 columns in 1 line, print 6 columns but with all lines (i mean if there are more)?

Comment: Sorry, i searched and i know now that i can do it with `cut -f 1-6`

Comment: It's not possible to get that output from that script given the posted sample input. idk if something changed...

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
$ cat cloudy.txt
word 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
hello 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.1 0.7 0.8 0.6 0.1 0.9

$ perl -lane '%kv=();%kv=map{ $_=>$F[$_] } 1..$#F; printf("$F[0] ");$i=0; for $x (reverse sort {$a <=> $b} values %kv) { @y=grep $x eq $kv{$_}, (keys %kv); printf("%d %.1f
 ",$y[0]+1,$x) if $i++ <5 } print "" ' cloudy.txt
word 11 10.0 10 9.0 9 8.0 8 7.0 7 6.0
hello 10 0.9 7 0.8 6 0.7 8 0.6 4 0.5

$
```